# What is `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast` and when should it be used?

Tags: c++, casting, c++17

Link to reference: [`std::reinterpret_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Should this be used when `weak_ptr` or `shared_ptr` are involved (Why? Always? Sometimes?)

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [this page on it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) which has more details on it then the link you provided.

Comment: Is it a Q about current, future std?

Comment: It seems I found the experimental namespace page only at first...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like all the other `std::*_pointer_cast` functions, this allows you to cast between different pointer types wrapped in `std::shared_ptr` as if the corresponding raw pointer was cast, but while retaining shared ownership.

So `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast<T>(ptr)` is (mostly) the same as `std::shared_ptr<T>(reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr.get()))`, with the important difference that the latter would cause the cast raw pointer to be stored in a *new* shared pointer which is not associated with the original one, so that the managed object will be double-deleted once by the original shared pointer complex and once by the new one (and the latter potentially with the wrong type).

Instead `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast<T>(ptr)` is (mostly) equivalent to `std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr, reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr.get()))`, which uses the so-called *aliasing constructor* of `std::shared_ptr`. It allows one to obtain a `std::shared_ptr` referencing any pointer (the second argument), while still having ownership associated with the original `shared_ptr` (first argument).

So you should use `std::reinterpret_pointer_cast` if you have a `std::shared_ptr` and you would have used `reinterpret_cast` if it had been a raw pointer instead.

Since use cases for `reinterpret_cast` are rare, you will be much more likely to use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` or `std::static_pointer_cast`, which are useful for down- and side-cast in class hierarchies.

Comment: What if casting from void* to say std::weak_ptr<T> (perhaps shared_ptr is the only relevant one) ? would that be a case, or should one just use reinterpret cast ? Also, could you provide some examples - perhaps also an example when it goes wrong using the non-pointer cast

Comment: @darune You can only cast between `std::shared_ptr` with this. You would need to `.lock()` the weak pointer before you cast. Casting `void*` to `std::shared_ptr<...>*` or `std::weak_ptr<...>*` would be done by `static_cast`, but I can't think of a case where this would be a good thing to do, you would instead hold a `shared_ptr` at the side calling the function taking `void*` and then you would pass it a raw pointer from `.get()` instead. As for examples, the line `std::shared_ptr<T>(reinterpret_cast<T*>(ptr.get()))` *always* causes UB if `ptr` is a non-empty `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I came up with another design so i ended up with no casts for the better - but I was curious on what to do if I should stay with casting. Im not sure it was a void* after all, I think it was a DWORD type after all - so i guess reinterpret_cast would be needed.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, I added that. In fact the standard defines `std::*_pointer_cast` in terms of the aliasing constructor.